# Array of Dynamic Dependent Select Box in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have an array of Depend select box which contains Universities and courses. Each university has its own course. and I have built the course dropdown which depends on the university. I can successfully get university course from server request but the problem is when I change the select university it's changing all course fields. How I can get rid of the problem please give me some ideas. Thanks

```js
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
    <div class="col col-md-12">
      <div v-for="(interest, index) in interests" :key="index" class="row">
        <div class="col col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group mb-4">
            <label for="select-ins">Interested Universities </label>
            <select
              v-model="interest.institute_id"
              class="form-control"
              @change="onChangeUniversity($event)"
            >
              <option disabled value="">Select a University</option>
              <option
                v-for="institute in institutes"
                :key="institute.id"
                :value="institute.id"
              >
                {{ institute.institute_name }}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group mb-4">
            <label>Interested Course</label>
            <select
              v-model="interest.course_id"
              class="form-control"
              @change="onChangeCourse($event)"
            >
              <option disabled value="">Select a Course</option>
              <option
                v-for="course in courses"
                :key="course.id"
                :value="course.id"
              >
                {{ course.course_name }}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-md-12 text-right">
          <div class="row ml-4">
            <div v-show="index == interests.length - 1">
              <button
                class="btn btn-warning mb-2 mr-2 btn-rounded"
                @click.prevent="add"
              >
                Add
              </button>
            </div>
            <div v-show="index || (!index && interests.length > 1)">
              <button
                class="btn btn-danger mb-2 mr-2 btn-rounded"
                @click.prevent="remove"
              >
                Remove
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      institutes: [],
      courses: [],
      interests: [
        {
          institute_id: "",
          course_id: "",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get("/institues").then((res) => {
      this.institutes = res.data;
    });
  },
  methods: {
    onChangeUniversity(event) {
      let universityId = event.target.value;
      axios.get(`/institute-course/${universityId}`).then((res) => {
        this.courses = res.data;
      });
    },
    add() {
      this.interests.push({
        institute_id: "",
        course_id: "",
      });
    },
    remove(index) {
      this.interests.splice(index, 1);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

check screenshot

http://prntscr.com/115mkn5

Comment: so if i get you right you want a solution where each institution is a array object and inside each institute you will have a array of objects with there related courses? correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: your data structur is not made smooth to display that exact functionality. right now your doing it the hard way. i will explain in a solution, give me a sec.

Answer (score 0):

lets start at your mounted hook.
you call for a API to receive all available institutes. so far so good. each institute got is own ID, this is important for later, lets keep that in mind.

now your using a function which will then call on a "change" event, like `onChangeUniversity` this is a good way on preventing to overload data in a page, nice idea just to fetch data only when they are needed.

then comes the tricky part which makes it difficult for you and everyone else reading your code.

you have this `courses` array in your data which normally belongs to the related institute. this array should not be handled as a second array apart from institutes, it should be a child of it.

like check this data structur:

```js
institutes: [
        {
          institute_name: "WhatEver1",
          id: 0,
          courses: [{ course: 1 }, { course: 2 }, { course: 3 }],
        }
      ]
```

instead of this:

```js
institutes: [
        {
          institute_name: "WhatEver1",
          id: 0,
        },
      ],
courses: [{ course: 1 }, { course: 2 }, { course: 3 }],
```

the first option above is a good nested way to display your data as loop inside a loop.
which means you have to push your courses inside your institute of choice with the belonged id.

your `onChangeUniversity` function should than do something like this:

```js
onChangeUniversity(event) {
      let universityId = event.target.value;
      axios.get(`/institute-course/${universityId}`).then((res) => {
        const foundedId = this.institutes.findIndex(institute => institute.id === universityId)
        this.institutes[foundedId].courses = res.data
      });
    },
```

after that its much easier to iterate over and display the data inside the options. and i am sure you will not have that issue anymore.
just try it like that first and give feedback.

---

### Update

```html
<div class="form-group mb-4">
            <label>Interested Course</label>
            <select
              v-model="interest.course_id"
              v-if="institute.courses.length !== 0" <-------HERE
              class="form-control"
              @change="onChangeCourse($event)"
            >
              <option disabled value="">Select a Course</option>
              <option
                v-for="course in institute.courses"
                :key="course.id"
                :value="course.id"
              >
                {{ course.course_name }}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
```

you need a render condition to stop your courses loop from being iterated when there is no data inside.

also make sure you await till the fetching of courses is completed.

```js
async onChangeUniversity(event) {
      let universityId = event.target.value;
      await axios.get(`/institute-course/${universityId}`).then((res) => {
        this.courses = res.data;
      });
    },
```

and also in your mounted hook

```js
async mounted() {
    await axios.get("/institues").then((res) => {
      this.institutes = res.data;
    });
  },
```

if you still struggle please give me a CodeSandbox of your current code.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. I have already change the array of data following your suggestions but I get an error I know the mistake is mine but If you have some suggestions for me or If you make the HTML for me then I will be pleased to u. Thanks @Deniz

http://prntscr.com/115vdmc

Comment: make sure u have a render condition for your courses loop. i update the answer.

Comment: @Dniz I am very grateful to you that u help me. please check the CodeSandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/country-institute-course-wvjk0?file=/src/App.vue